# Add data to DataTable columns in multiple text files

Tags: c#

I'm trying to export data in multiple files to a single datatable. I was able to add data to the dataset but it doesn't provide the output that I need. I guess it should be an error in my loop and I tried in different ways but failed to get the correct output. Given below the output that I receive:

[image: Received output]

And this is the output I need:

[image: Desired output]

Please refer the coding that I used, and please help me to find where I'm going wrong. Thanks in advance.

```cs
    OpenFileDialog thisDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    thisDialog.Multiselect = true;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    if (thisDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        foreach (string files in thisDialog.FileNames)
        {
            //each file generates two columns
            DataColumn column1 = new DataColumn();
            dt.Columns.Add(column1);
            DataColumn column2 = new DataColumn();
            dt.Columns.Add(column2);
            using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(files))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.Contains("DISKXFER"))
                    {
                        string dataLine = line.ToString();
                        string[] split = dataLine.Split(',');
                        int result = split.Length;
                        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                        dt.Rows.Add(split[2], split[3]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

Comment: what file are you trying to read? Is this textfile? Please provide sample input, because as I understand your solution you are reading textfiles and splitting with ','.

Comment: @JRC Yes i'm trying to read a text file. I'm reading the lines which contain the word "DISKXFER" one by one in each text file. the line is something like this: "DISKXFER,T0001,0.5,0.0". I'm splitting the line and taking "0.5" and "0.0" to two columns and add new rows for each line. Thanks

Comment: what contains your `split`?

Comment: @WiiMaxx the dataline is something like this: "DISKXFER,T0001,0.5,0.0". I'm splitting the line using the delimiter ",". then the line split into 4 elements. I'm taking split[2]="0.5" and split[3]="0.0" to two columns and add new rows for each line

Comment: ok so your hdisk.. are your column headers right? and will your row's always numbers?

Comment: and in your example above you are using 2files or just one?

Comment: The examples shows output of two files

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a new row for each DISKXFER line in each file, with only the first two columns populated - dt.rows.add does this.

You should fill in more of the columns in dr, then add dr to the table.

Comment: I generated two columns first and added drs to the table. then i receive the columns and rows as i expected. But the values in the rows are incorrect. They are the same values belongs to the last line. PLease help me on this. thanks